HMS MapKit ERROR TileDataSource.cpp:52: http status code = 403
I am trying to apply HMS Mapkit to my flutter app. However my map only able to render partially gives me errors like below in the debug terminal:
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileDataSource.cpp:52: http status code = 403
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileBuilderTask.cpp:137: [ErrorDetector] Load tile: 16/16x=51240&y=32202-0-1 failed! 3
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileDataSource.cpp:128: [ErrorDetector] Tile Error: 3; tileID: 16/16x=51240&y=32202-0-1
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileBuilderTask.cpp:137: [ErrorDetector] Load tile: 16/16x=51240&y=32202-0-1 failed! 2
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileBuilderTask.cpp:137: [ErrorDetector] Load tile: 16/16x=51240&y=32201-0-1 failed! 3
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileDataSource.cpp:128: [ErrorDetector] Tile Error: 3; tileID: 16/16x=51240&y=32201-0-1
I/MapRender(16019): ERROR TileBuilderTask.cpp:137: [ErrorDetector] Load tile: 16/16x=51239&y=32203-0-1 failed! 3

I tried to find solutions about this error and mostly tell me that is API Configuration in AppGallery Connect issue which I have follow all the steps given in this link.
The following is build.gradle sample:
android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
}

// Load keystore properties
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace <appId>
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId <appId>
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        // targetSdkVersion 34 will cause the app to crash
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    // Signing configuration for release build
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            // Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation and optimization for release builds 
            minifyEnabled true 
            // Unused resources will be removed. 
            shrinkResources true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2')
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:hwid:6.12.0.300"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0"
    implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.0.0.300"
}

